# Named routes in param pre-conditions

Tags: node.js, routes, express

I'd like to use a [Route Param Pre-Condition](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#route-param%20pre-conditions) to fetch portfolio items by "slug" if the :slug parameter is set in the URL. I also, however, would like to use a `RegExp` to match the URI. Are named captures supported in node? Can I give that `([-\w]+)` capture a name so the *slug* pre-condition gets fired?

```
app.param('slug', function(req, res, next, slug){
  // get thing from database by slug
})

//app.get('/work/view/:slug', function(req, res){
app.get(/^\/work\/view\/([-\w]+)/, function(req, res){
  // render view
})
```

Comment: maybe refactor and have 2 routes having the `checkSlug` as first item in the stack?

Comment: sorry, not following; what's `checkSlug`?

Comment: Interesting, did it work? BTW, for future questions, you don't need to put everything in your code that is not relevant to the question. For this one, you don't need all of the insides of the callback function in the routes for us to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but as far as I know, there is no direct way do do what you need. However, you can use a named param ("slug") and add a Regex precodition along with your own to achieve the same effect.

Take a look at visionmedia's `express-params` module [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-params). I expect it to be maintained just fine since it's from the creator of express itself.

What you are gonna do (after installing express-params) is basically something like this:

```
app.param('slug', /^[-\w]+$/);

app.param('slug', function(req, res, next, slug){
  // get thing from database by slug
});

app.get('/work/view/:slug', function(req, res){
  //render view
});
```

I did not test any of this though.