# Nodejs, Express. Is there a way to store/get what POST params are required in an endpoint to show to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm writing some test page to debug my API and expose it neatly.

Using Express [app.routes](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.routes) I can get a neat list of all the endpoints my application implements, so I can show to the users the list of possible POST requests.

However, most of them require some POST parameters, which the server obtains from the requests in this way, for example (/api/ping requires a "ping" POST parameter):

```
app.post("/api/ping", function(req, res) //
{
    var ping = req.param('ping');

    if( ping ) {    
        res.out.message = "Pong";
    } else {
        res.out.message = "Ping missing";
    }

    return exports.respond(res);
});
```

I noticed that app.routes has a "keys" and a "params" keys in the endpoints list, but I think this seems to be used only for parameters that are in the path (for example "userid" as parameter when someone requests for the "/user/:userid" path). I believe express calls these stored parameters "pre-conditions".

Is there any way to add preconditions like these to express app for POST parameters so that they are also shown in the app.routes object and I can display neatly which parameters are required for which endpoint?

Comment: Can you clarify on the preconditions part?

Comment: If you want to get input in post method, you can use "request.body" property. Check this http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body

Comment: @Kuryaki I can't link directly to the guide because they changed the wording and now they don't call it preconditions anymore. But I meant something like what they do in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626193/named-routes-in-param-pre-conditions). Anyway, I edited my question.

Comment: @hilarudeens thanks, but that's for getting the parameters already sent on a request. I want a way to get what parameters are required for that request, before doing the request. It looks like [app.routes](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.routes) has a way of storing this in some way but I don't know how to make use of it, or if it only works for parameters that are sent as part of the path.